# Boostrap indenting columns in row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. Why is the second row with 3 columns (`col-sm-3`, `col-sm-6` and `col-sm-3`) being indented, the other two rows have a wider width? How can I make all rows the same width?

```css
.header {background-color: #9933cc;}
    .menu ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }
 .menu li {
  background-color :#33b5e5;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
 }
 .aside {background-color: #33b5e5;}
 .footer {background-color: #0099cc;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>
 <div class='row'>
  <div class='header'>
   <h1>China</h1>
  </div><!--end header-->
 </div>
 <div class='row'>
  <div class='menu col-sm-3'>
   <ul>
    <li>The Flight</li>
    <li>The City</li>
    <li>The Island</li>
    <li>The Food</li>
   </ul>
  </div><!--end menu-->
  <div class='col-sm-6'>
   <h1>The City</h1>
   <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
   <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-3'>
   <div class='aside'>
    <h2>What?</h2>
    <p>Chania is a city on the island of Crete.</p>
    <h2>Where?</h2>
    <p>Crete is a Greek island in the Mediterranean Sea.</p>
    <h2>How?</h2>
    <p>You can reach Chania airport from all over Europe.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class='row'>
  <div class='footer'>
   <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
  </div><!--end footer-->
 </div>
</div><!--end container-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.col-sm-3 and .col-md-6` adds padding to the `div` elements.

Wrap the header and footer in col-sm-12

HTML

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class='header'>
        <h1>China</h1>
   </div><!--end header-->
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
 <div class='footer'>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
 </div><!--end footer-->
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/j0mdouvc/1/)

Adding `.col-sm-12` class to `.footer` and `.header` div's don't change because, background-color property is applied on `.header` and `.footer` and color is applied including the padding.

Wrapping these elements `(footer and header) divs` in `.col-sm-12` adds padding to parent elements.

Comment: Nice! It worked. I am curious why adding these classes to the header and footer div tags do not work and why do they only work when a separate div is used having the `col-sm-12` added to it? If you could explain this to me that would be wonderful.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!